# Brew doctor shows warnings How to solve it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I am new to OSX while running

```
brew doctor
```

shows the following warnings.

```
Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool installed. 
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.


 Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
`brew link <formula>` will cause other formulae to detect them during
the `./configure` step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

openssl
```

Is there anyway to solve the error without reinstalling OS?

I need to install ruby rails, it shows some errors while running

```
rails server
```

command. I think the problem is due to the above warnings.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

@Yahya, I ran into the same problem and managed to fix it after reading this thread: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29989

I've tried both suggested solutions (reinstalling the essentials package vs copying only the install_name_tool binary) and both worked equally fine (I've given examples for each of them below)

Therefore for **Yosemite** systems I recommend the fast 'clone&copy' approach, where as for the **Mavericks** ones - the much slower package replacement.

### Yosemite OS

First check the current version of install_name_tool

```
$ otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool
/usr/bin/install_name_tool
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 88.3.3)
```

Now clone the Yosemite compatible binary from Github and replace the one in your /usr/bin folder:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cinic/install-name-tool
Cloning into 'install-name-tool'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 3
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/install_name_tool /usr/bin/install_name_tool.orig
$ sudo cp install-name-tool/install_name_tool /usr/bin/
```

Finally check if the version is updated and if homebrew is fixed:

```
$ otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool 
/usr/bin/install_name_tool:
    /usr/lib/libxcselect.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
```

Finally

```
$ rm -fr install-name-tool/
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/install_name_tool.orig
```

### Mavericks

Download the **Mavericks** installer from App store

```
$ open /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
$ open /Volumes/OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/Packages/Essentials.pkg
```

After the package is installed, check if the `brew doctor` output.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Homebrew, it will often look for items you have and link them. It looks like it's done that with openssl. You have three options:

Uninstall and reinstall openssl

```
brew uninstall openssl
brew install openssl
```

Try upgrading openssl

```
brew update openssl
```

Or you can try unlinking openssl (though, only do this if you know where you openssl is)

```
brew unlink openssl
```

Comment: So the issue is fixed for you? If so, awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and would get the warning that "/usr/bin/install_name_tool" was outdated.

The problem is that Xcode's install_name_tool has been updated, while the one in the system is outdated.
This can be solved by copying Xcode's install_name_tool to the system.
Use this command :

`sudo cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents//Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool /usr/bin/install_name_tool`

install_name_tool should now be updated.